# Cast Type X from Assembly A to Type X in Assembly B

Tags: c#, casting

- I have 2 projects in a solution. (Call them A and B). They both became assemblies.
- I have a shared project (call it S) referenced by the other 2 projects
- I have a class (call it C) in project S
- I serialize it in project A
- I deserialize it in project B
- I cannot cast it to C

The problem is if that the deserialized object's type is "C, A" but when I write code:

```
var c = GetDeserializedObject() as C;
```

c will be null because `GetDeserializedObject() is C` returns false.

**Question:**

Any idea how should I get this work? Use class C in assembly B that was serialized in assembly A.

**Notes:**

I use this code to serialize my object:

```
var serialized = MessagePackSerializer.Typeless.Serialize(this);
File.WriteAllBytes(outputFilePath, serialized);
```

And this code to deserialize it:

```
MessagePackSerializer.Typeless.Deserialize(File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilePath)) as C;
```

**Additional comments:**

I cannot use BinaryFormatter since class C contains several properties that's types are not [Serializable]

I tried to use Newtonsoft Json Serializer as well, but I couldn't read out the data during deserialization. If I serialize it with types, then there is a type mismatch. If I serialize them without types in some cases the system cannot instantiate the interface types nor abstract class types. Because my classes look like this:

```
class C {
    IMyInterface i;
}

class MyClass : IMyInterface { }
```

And I use it like this:

```
var c = new C {
    i = new MyClass()
};
```

Comment: Casting or (de)serializing? Why are you serializing and not just passing class C along, letting the .net framework do its work?

Comment: The problem could be `MyClass`. Is it declared in the shared project?

Comment: Yes MyClass is declared in the Shared Project

Comment: @Icepickle The use case it. The 2 assemblies are 2 different programs. They communicate thru a config file

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you able to serialize and deserialize an instance of C within the same project? I'm wondering if the issue is really related to the 2 different assemblies or with the `C` class itself.

Comment: Yes it works if it is in the same assembly. I even had unit tests for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to deserialize:

```
MessagePack.Formatters.TypelessFormatter.BindToType = typeName =>
{
    var typeWithoutAssemblyName = typeName.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
    return Type.GetType(typeWithoutAssemblyName ?? typeName, false);
};

return MessagePackSerializer.Typeless.Deserialize(File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilePath)) as C;
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use JSON serializer & deserializer with TypeNameHandlig flag enabled so it will take care of the Interface serialization in your class C

```
var indented = Formatting.Indented; var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }; string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wizardConf, indented, settings);
```

You can see the details [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1119121/Serialize-and-Deserialize-Classes-with-Interface-P)

Comment: From what I read in the [documentation of MessagePack](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#object-serialization), the [`Typeless`](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#typeless) serialization should take care of that as well. So this doesn't really answer the question by the OP, it just offers a potential alternative (the OP didn't state if he was looking for alternatives to MessagePack)

Comment: @Icepickle is right. This is a nice workaround, but to avoid extra work the `MessagePack` works with `TypelessFormatter`